# Quotient with positive second derivative in the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, convexity

I am studying the quotient of
 $$f(\varepsilon) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  \frac{i^2}{2^{\varepsilon i^2}}$$
and $$g(\varepsilon) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{2^{\varepsilon i^2}}$$
for some $\varepsilon>0.$

Consider then the function $h(\varepsilon):=f(\varepsilon)/g(\varepsilon).$

Doing some numerics, I found that the second derivative of the function $h$ satisfies $\liminf_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} h''(\varepsilon)>0.$

I was not really able to quantify what the limiting expression is, but I am sure the second derivative stays positive as $\varepsilon$ tends to zero.

Unfortunately, one cannot really evaluate the expressions, but perhaps there is some nice convexity trick to show that

$$\liminf_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} h''(\varepsilon)>0$$

cause I do not really see where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect for small $\epsilon$ the approximation of the sum by an integral to be accurate. Here is a plot of $h(\epsilon)$ (blue curve) and 
$$H(\epsilon)=\frac{\int_0^\infty x^2 2^{-\epsilon x^2}\,dx}{\int_0^\infty 2^{-\epsilon x^2}\,dx}=\frac{1}{\epsilon\log 4},$$
(gold curve).

[image]

This would imply that the second derivative diverges as $\epsilon^{-3}/\log 2$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.